# SSRS - Number formatted as percentage is formatted as custom in Excel export

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report that has a number formatted as a percentage:

[image]

When the SSRS report is exported to and opened in Excel, it displays the number as a "Custom" format:

[image]

I don't want the number to be formatted as a "Custom" number type. It doesn't render correctly in some apps that can open Excel files. How can I design the SSRS report to export to Excel with the number formatted as a "Percentage"?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that it is currently possible. Regardless of what you have for the FORMAT, Excel will show it as Custom.

I remember seeing several requests to change it years ago (2005-2009ish) but they were closed as Works As Designed.

You can submit a request for a change but you'll probably get "Sorry, we would like to look at this further, but we just don’t have the time right now."